# How we can inherit BaseModel class in odoo

Tags: abstract-class, odoo-9

Need to inherit BaseModel class and add a new attribute like

```py
_auto = True 
_register = False
_name = None
_columns = {}
_constraints = []
_custom = False
_defaults = {}
_rec_name = None
_parent_name = 'parent_id'
_parent_store = False
_parent_order = False
_date_name = 'date'
_order = 'id'
_sequence = None
_description = None
_needaction = False
_translate = True
```

Use this attribute in all models so need to be declare as a global

example :

```py
from openerp import api, fields, models, _

class NewClass(models.Model):

    _name = 'object name'
    _new_attribute = 'vaule'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from openerp import api, fields, models, _

class BaseModelExtend(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'basemodel.extend'
    models.BaseModel._navigation = 'id'

    def _register_hook(self, cr):
        '''
        Register method in BaseModel 
        '''
        @api.multi
        def navigate_field(self):
            #CODE
            return True
        models.BaseModel.navigate_field = navigate_field
        return super(BaseModelExtend, self)._register_hook(cr)
```

Answer (score 0):

1- create a new python file my_basemodel.py

2- add your custom methods like this

```
    from openerp.osv.orm import BaseModel
#    built your attribute. you can refer inbuilt code to create attribute.
```

Comment: Not want to use already declare attributes in new class. First need to be add a new attribute in BaseModel class

_navigation = False

Class SaleOrder(models.Model):
 _name = 'sale.order'
 _navigation = 'partner_id'

Comment: try this code! but you have to build your attribute.