# Odoo inherit using name of class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, odoo

I have a problem when i was try to inherit on odoo from core odoo. In the document of odoo, i have to inherit from variable "_name", But in this case the variable is None, `_name = None` . So, i was try to inherit from class but still not working.

This is a class from core :

```
class BaseModel(object):
```

And This is my code :

```
from openerp import fields, models, api

class BaseModel(models.BaseModel):
    _inherit = 'BaseModel'
```

Comment: please provide a minimum working example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, show what is None, e.g. using print()

Comment: Usually, every class have _name. Buat in my case the class doesn't have _name. i mean, the class is have _name but the value is None.

Comment: try class BaseModel(models.Model): _inherit = "base.module"

Comment: jup, also just saw that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44542771/how-we-can-inherit-basemodel-class-in-odoo, I guess it is fine to be None, you assign the name in the new class

Comment: Why are you inheriting from `BaseModel` instead of `Model`?

Comment: Because i want to change the ValidationError from core of odoo, many people say to if i want to change something from core, the best way's is i have to inherit it, and edit what i want form inherit, not in core.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `_inherit`, only if you inherit from an existing odoo model. If you only want to create a new model you can use:

```
class CustomModel(models.AbstractModel):
    _name="custom.model"
```

(AbstractModel is the same as BaseModel, but it's used in source instead of BaseModel).

And then you can inherit this model with

```
class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    _inherit="custom.model"
    _name="another.model"
```

Comment: The problem is ```_name=None``` in core

Comment: Models have `_name`, this is not a model just a python class, that you can inherit using traditional python inheritance, like in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't understand what do you mean. What i know about odoo, if we want to inherite. We have to use the string from _name, after that we can do inherite in our class.

Comment: You are using Odoo's inheritance mechanisms to inherit from a model. The BaseModel is not a model, but a superclass for all models. You are inheriting it with python inheritance. You cannot extend it directly unlike odoo models, but you can create an AbstractModel modifying it, and then inherit that.

Comment: Please refer to the odoo ORM documentation here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/saas-13/reference/orm.html